# Calling while loop function in main function, and won't move past after completing loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

So, I'm creating a program for class to take orders of cookies, and the guideline is to create separate functions. Unfortunately, when I try to get into the subsequent functions, it doesn't seem to be doing that, and I was wondering where my problem may be at? I've tried playing around with parameters and data types and seeing if that would do anything, unfortunately I have come up short.

I appreciate all your help guys.

For people looking at this in the future, I've completed this program to work, and this first bit of code is the original code I was asking the question about... carry on to next portion.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int getThinMints();
int getOreos();

int main(){
   getThinMints();
   getOreos();

    return 0;
}

int getThinMints(){
    int numThinMints;
    int min_order = 0;
    int max_order = 10;

        while ((numThinMints < 0 || numThinMints > 10))
        {
            cout << "Enter the number of Thin Mints (0-10): ";
            cin >> numThinMints;
            cin.ignore(100, '\n');
            cin.clear();
        }
}

int getOreos(){
    int numOreos;
    int min_order = 0;
    int max_order = 10;

        while ((numOreos < 0 || numOreos > 10))
        {
            cout << "Enter the number of Thin Mints (0-10): ";
            cin >> numOreos;
            cin.ignore(100, '\n');
            cin.clear();
        }
}
```

New code I implemented for the complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int getCookies(string cookietype, int max_order); // cookie input function prototype

int main()
{
    int thin_mints;
    int lemonUps;
    int lemonades;
    int samoas;
    int tagalongs;
    int dosidos;
    int trefoils;
    int thanksalot;
    int toffee;
    int caramel;
    
    int max_order = 10; // 10 cookies max per type
    int orderNumber = 0; // initial order number
    double cPrice = 5.0; // $5 per order
    
    string qtyStr = "(0-10): ";
    string cookie1 = "Enter the number of Thin Mints " + qtyStr;
    string cookie2 = "Enter the number of Lemon-Ups " + qtyStr;
    string cookie3 = "Enter the number of Lemonades " + qtyStr;
    string cookie4 = "Enter the number of Samoas " + qtyStr;
    string cookie5 = "Enter the number of Tagalongs " + qtyStr;
    string cookie6 = "Enter the number of Do-si-dos " + qtyStr;
    string cookie7 = "Enter the number of Trefoils " + qtyStr;
    string cookie8 = "Enter the number of Thanks-A-Lot " + qtyStr;
    string cookie9 = "Enter the number of Toffee-tastic " + qtyStr;
    string cookie10 = "Enter the number of Caramel Chocolate Chip " + qtyStr;
    string fname, lname, address, cityStZip;

    bool moreOrders = true;

    ofstream outFile; // This will open a .txt file named 'na_orders' with an invoice for the cookie orders

    // Open the output file
    outFile.open ("na_orders.txt", ios::out); 
    while (moreOrders)
    {
        fname = lname = address = cityStZip = "";

        cout << "Enter the customers first and last name (or q to quit): " <<endl;
        cin >> fname;
        if (fname == "q")
            break;

        orderNumber ++;
        cin >> lname;
        cin.ignore();
        cin.clear();

        while (address.length() == 0)
        {
            cout << "Enter the " << fname << " " << lname << "'s address: ";
            getline(cin, address);
        }

        while (cityStZip.length() == 0)
        {
            cout << "Enter the " << fname << " " << lname << "'s city, state and zip code: ";
            getline(cin, cityStZip);
        }

        

        /* The following section is going to be where the user will
        input their specificed amounts for each cookie type */

        thin_mints = getCookies(cookie1, max_order); // input for Thin Mints
        cout << "Thin Mints amount: " << thin_mints << endl;

        lemonUps = getCookies(cookie2, max_order); // input for Lemon-Ups
        cout << "Lemon-Ups amount: " << lemonUps << endl;

        lemonades = getCookies(cookie3, max_order); // input for Lemonades
        cout << "Lemonades amount: " << lemonades << endl;

        samoas = getCookies(cookie4, max_order); // input for Samoas
        cout << "Samoas amount: " << samoas << endl;

        tagalongs = getCookies(cookie5, max_order); // input for Tagalongs
        cout << "Tagalongs amount: " << tagalongs << endl;

        dosidos = getCookies(cookie6, max_order); // input for Do-si-dos
        cout << "Do-si-dos amount: " << dosidos << endl;

        trefoils = getCookies(cookie7, max_order); // input for Trefoils
        cout << "Trefoils amount: " << trefoils << endl;

        thanksalot = getCookies(cookie8, max_order); // input for Thanks-A-Lot
        cout << "Thanks-A-Lot amount: " << thanksalot << endl;

        toffee = getCookies(cookie9, max_order); // input for Toffee-tastic
        cout << "Toffee-tastic amount: " << toffee << endl;

        caramel = getCookies(cookie10, max_order); // input for Caramel Chocolate Chip
        cout << "Caramel Chocolate Chip amount: " << caramel << endl;


        if (outFile.is_open())
        {
            outFile << "================================" << endl;
            outFile << "=== Girl Scout Cookie Invoice ===" << endl;
            outFile << "================================\n" << endl;

            string dateStr;
            time_t result = time(NULL);
            dateStr = ctime(&result);

            outFile << dateStr << endl;
            outFile << fname << " " << lname << endl;
            outFile << address << endl;
            outFile << cityStZip << endl;
            outFile << endl;
            outFile << "Order Number: " << orderNumber << endl;
            outFile << endl;
            outFile << "Dear " << fname << " " << lname << ":" << endl;
            outFile << endl;
            outFile << "Your Girl Scout Cookie order has arrived." << endl;
            outFile << "Your order consists of the following:" << endl;
            outFile << "-------------------------------------------------" << endl;
            outFile << "|" << setw(14) << "Cookie" << setw(11) << "|" << setw(9) << "Quantity" << setw(2) << "|" << setw(7) << "Cost" << setw(5) << "|" << endl;
            outFile << "-------------------------------------------------" << endl;
            outFile << "|" << setw(11) << "Thin Mints" << setw(14) << "|" << setw(9) << thin_mints << setw(2) << "|" << setw(2) << "$" << setw(8) << fixed << setprecision(2) << thin_mints * cPrice << setw(2) << "|" << endl;
            outFile << "|" << setw(9) << "Lemon-up" << setw(16) << "|" << setw(9) << lemonUps << setw(2) << "|" << setw(2) << "$" << setw(8) << fixed << setprecision(2) << lemonUps * cPrice << setw(2) << "|" << endl;
            outFile << "|" << setw(10) << "Lemonades" << setw(15) << "|" << setw(9) << lemonades << setw(2) << "|" << setw(2) << "$" << setw(8) << fixed << setprecision(2) << lemonades * cPrice << setw(2) << "|" << endl;
            outFile << "|" << setw(7) << "Samoas" << setw(18) << "|" << setw(9) << samoas << setw(2) << "|" << setw(2) << "$" << setw(8) << fixed << setprecision(2) << samoas * cPrice << setw(2) << "|" << endl;
            outFile << "|" << setw(10) << "Tagalongs" << setw(15) << "|" << setw(9) << tagalongs << setw(2) << "|" << setw(2) << "$" << setw(8) << fixed << setprecision(2) << tagalongs * cPrice << setw(2) << "|" << endl;
            outFile << "|" << setw(10) << "Do-si-dog" << setw(15) << "|" << setw(9) << dosidos << setw(2) << "|" << setw(2) << "$" << setw(8) << fixed << setprecision(2) << dosidos * cPrice << setw(2) << "|" << endl;
            outFile << "|" << setw(9) << "Trefoils" << setw(16) << "|" << setw(9) << trefoils << setw(2) <<"|" << setw(2) << "$" << setw(8) << fixed << setprecision(2) << trefoils * cPrice << setw(2) << "|" << endl;
            outFile << "|" << setw(13) << "Thanks-A-Lot" << setw(12) << "|" << setw(9) << thanksalot << setw(2) << "|" << setw(2) << "$" << setw(8) << fixed << setprecision(2) << thanksalot * cPrice << setw(2) << "|" << endl;
            outFile << "|" << setw(14) << "Toffee-Tastic" << setw(11) << "|" << setw(9) << toffee << setw(2) << "|" << setw(2) << "$" << setw(8) << fixed << setprecision(2) << toffee * cPrice << setw(2) << "|" << endl;
            outFile << "|" << setw(23) << "Caramel Chocolate Chip" << setw(2) << "|" << setw(9) << caramel << setw(2) << "|" << setw(2) << "$" << setw(8) << fixed << setprecision(2) << caramel * cPrice << setw(2) << "|" << endl;
            outFile << "-------------------------------------------------" << endl;
            outFile << "|" << setw(33) << "Total Due:" << setw(3) << "|" << setw(2) << "$" << setw(8) << fixed << setprecision(2) << cPrice * (thin_mints + lemonUps + lemonades + samoas + tagalongs + dosidos + trefoils + thanksalot + toffee + caramel) << setw(2) << "|" << endl;
            outFile << "-------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        }
    }
}


int getCookies(string cookietype, int max_order)
{
    int quantity = -1;
    int min_order = 0;

    while ((quantity < min_order) || (quantity > max_order))
    {
        cout << cookietype;
        cin >> quantity;
        cin.clear();
    }
    return quantity;
}
```

Comment: In the `getThinMints` function, what is the initial value of `numThinMints`? In C++ uninitialized local variables really are uninitialized, and they will have *indeterminate* values. Using an indeterminate value in any way leads to *undefined behavior*. You have the same problem in `getOreos`.

Comment: Both functions have undefined behaviour. You neved initialize `numOreos` and `numThinMints` before the first read access. Replace the `while` loops, with `do ... while`

Comment: Sidenote: Both functions are asking for Thin Mints, the second should be asking for Oreos. And both should return something, e.g. `return numOreos;`.

Comment: In `getThinMints()`, the variable `numThinMints` is uninitialised before the loop.   You've made the mistake of thinking that it will be initialised to something (e.g. to zero) but you're flat out wrong.     So evaluating the loop condition gives undefined behaviour.     Try initialising `numThinMints` to zero (or to a value for which the loop condition is true) BEFORE the loop.       Similar comment for the variable `numOreos` in the function `getOreos()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enter the value of a variable **before** you use it, not afterwards. For example

```
    for (;;) // loop until we break
    {
        // get the number of oreos
        cout << "Enter the number of Oreos (0-10): ";
        cin >> numOreos;
        // check the number of oreos is OK
        if (numOreos >= 0 && numOreos <= 10)
            break; // quit the loop if it is
        // ignore any extraneous input and try again
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
        cin.clear();
    }
```

See that the test on the number of Oreos happens after the user has input a value, not before.

In your code with the while loop you were checking the value of `numOreos` when it had not yet been given a value. C++ programs are sequences of instructions and the order things happen is important. They are not declarations of intent where you just say 'I want the variable to be within these values' and leave it up the computer to figure it out.